# Create Only If Update isnt possible Mysql With php FOR Loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, insert

How can I Update a table If The Columns might exist or might not?

```
     AI|   UNIQUE TOGETHER   |UNIQUE|UNIQUE|UNIQUE|
     ______________________________________________
    |id|movieid|episodenumber|link1    |link2|link3|
    |--|-------|-------------|---------|-----|-----|
    | 1|12     |1            |somelink |NULL |NULL |
    | 2|12     |2            |somelink2|NULL |NULL | 
    | 3|12     |3            |somelink3|NULL |NULL |        
    | 4|12     |4            |somelink4|NULL |NULL |                                          
    |__|_______|_____________|_________|_____|_____|
```

And Lets say I insert a link with movieid=12 and episodenumber=2 the link autochecks if there is such movieid+episode number so it already exists and checks if code1 is not null then Update and heres my so far code:

```
$episodesamount=$_POST['episodesamount'];
$query='INSERT INTO episodes VALUES';
$episodesparts = array();
for($x=1; $x<=$episodesamount; $x++){
    $episodeslink="episode".$x;
    $episodesparts[] = "( '','$_POST[epimovieid]','$x','NULL',$_POST[$episodeslink],NULL)";
    }
$inserts2 = $query .= implode(',', $episodesparts);
$inserts2ed =$inserts2."ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code2=VALUES(code1)"; //Values code1 I hope its the failed to insert code but Im not quite sure it is...
echo "<h1><font color='lightgreen'>Episodes Added Successfully!</h1>";
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Did you receive any error messages? It looks like your build your query, but never execute it before your echo. It looks fine, as long as your table has the `UNIQUE KEY` on `movieid,episodenumber`.

Comment: Unknown column 'ANYLINKITEST' in 'field list'

Comment: Dump $inserts2ed  and edit your question with the result

Comment: Yes it works on insert but did you read the question? I need to update it

Comment: `$_POST[$episodeslink]` looks to be a string, so it should be quoted `'$_POST[$episodeslink]'`

Comment: Thanks @Sean that was my mistake, But That unfortunately is not answering my question It still sais anything I put After UPDATE it just outputs as that whatever I put as unknown field ...